# How long does pasture need to be rested to prevent worm re-infestation?

Tags: health, parasites, horses

I'm moving my horses into new paddocks where there hasn't been horses for 4 weeks. I'm wondering if there can still be worms in these paddocks.

Is it possible to rest paddocks for long enough to prevent worm re-infestation?
If so how long does pasture need to be rested to prevent worm re-infestation?

Comment: What types of worms did your horses have? There are thousands of species which all have different life cycles. It's not possible to answer this question for all types of "worms" but I'm sure the answer is much longer than 4 weeks...on the order of months, if not years

Comment: I'll post an answer at some point. I'm just out of time atm

Comment: In addition to waiting, you can apply nitrolime to reduce worms.